# webpack dev server leading to freezing of the system

Tags: inotify

I was getting errors on using `npm start` in my react application. which goes like this
 `ENOSPC system limit for file watcher reached`
 I updated my npm and node versions but still i was getting this problem. After a little research i got to know that there is something known as inotify which watches different files and i need to increase its file watching limit. I used this code
 `echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p` 
 in my terminal to increase the file watcher limit. After this i was succesfully able to do `npm start` and got my project running in localhost:3000, But this slowed my system incredibly, and it freezed every now and then. I highly suspect this is due to increasing number of file watchers. Is it the case if yes what should i do now??

Answer (score 0):

**Inotify** monitors the system event changes and with the change that you have made you are monitoring more files than before; monitoring that of course, affects to the general system behaviour.

If you really want to "tune" that value, check with the following command how many current user watches are:

`lsof | grep inotify | wc -l`

After that, simply put a slightly bigger value to that result to avoid the issue in **fs.inotify.max_user_watches**; a value that may be much smaller than *524288* and that will help you to consumme much less resources.

Comment: I got the value of 208 by the command, should i set the maximum user watches to 500

Comment: Depending on you free RAM I would put even more; for example in Ubuntu and Debian systems the default value is 8192; If possible put that one, a value that as you can see is much less than 524288.

Answer (score 0):

### 524288: a (too big) magic number

As you probably did, I followed the suggestion to set `max_user_watches` value to an higher number than the default, once the IDE was complaining about it.
I don't know from where the `524288` comes from, but after using it for months I can say for sure that it can cause problems, even for a system with plenty of RAM.

**For who is searching for an answer to the same warning message:**

If you want to change the limit, do it by little steps, don't go directly to 524288 or so.

### Webpack dev server optimization (don't hide the problem... fix it!)

The purpose of dev-server & hot-reloading is to save you some time by watching the files with a high chance of being updated during development.

But how many times do you change the code in `node_modules` folder? Probably not many, so...

```js
devServer: {

...
        watchOptions: {
            ignored: /node_modules/
        },

...

},
```

With this option the dev server will concentrate only on files that you really need to monitor to benefit from the hot reloading.

If you need to change npm dependencies, then it's better to stop the server, install/remove packages, and finally restart it.

### Script to check processes using file watcher

There's an [interesting script](https://github.com/fatso83/dotfiles/blob/master/utils/scripts/inotify-consumers) on GitHub that prints all the processes watching files, with their respective file number count.

It's a lifesafer!

`intellij-current/plugins/JavaScriptLanguage/jsLanguageServicesIm`

I suspect that this is comes from Jetbrains' Node.js Code assistance feature, it's watching another 13k of files, on top of the ~10k watched by the dev server.

Good luck with your best-setting search! :-)